# Rally custom dropdown to multiSelect

Tags: drop-down-menu, rally, appsdk2

We have a custom drop down and need to make it a multiSelect. Your answer gives me hope but so far, I have not figured out how this can be done. I played around how to build custom grids using JavaScript. Is it possible to make an existing custom drop-down list to a multiSelect? If it is, can be it used in the existing Rally screens or do we have to use interactive grids to be able to update the field?

Please advice on how this can be achieved.

Thank you, Rajani.

Answer (score 0):

A custom dropdown cannot be turned into a custom multiselect. There are no custom fileds in Rally of mulitselect type. You may write a custom app using [AppSDK2](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/) with a [MultiObjectPicker](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.picker.MultiObjectPicker)

For example, here is a rallymutiobjectpicker that allows selection of multiple testsets:

```
this._testSetPicker = Ext.create('Rally.ui.picker.MultiObjectPicker', {
            itemId:'testsetpicker',
            modelType: 'testset'
});
```

Later you may use [_getRecordValue()](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.picker.MultiObjectPicker-method-_getRecordValue) to get the array of selected records:

```
var selectedTestSets = this._testSetPicker._getRecordValue();
```

A [custom grid](https://help.rallydev.com/custom-grid) and a [custom html app](https://help.rallydev.com/custom-html) are not the same. 
A UI component created with AppSDK2 cannot be added to a custom grid, and cannot be added to existing Rally pages, e.g. a Defect or User Story details page, or any summary page.

The MultiObjectPicker can only be used in a [custom code](https://help.rallydev.com/custom-html#code) that you write and then copy your deployment html and paste it into a custom html page.

The [developer portal](https://help.rallydev.com/for-developers) also has links to [great videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3PQ-IsMxhG14aDViKxlPZASIrHatNkft) by David Thomas. See all the links in this post for details.

Comment: Thank you, how can the new multiOBjectPicker be used? Is it possible to add the new field on existing Defect screens (i doubt it)? or it has to accessed through custom grid apps?

Comment: It is not possible to add a new UI component to an existing Defect screens or to a custom gird. It can only be added to your custom code. I updated the answer with links to help pages that describe a difference between a custom grid and a custom html/javascript app.

Comment: With custom code, is it possible to write to Rally? I am wondering if we can write custom code to mimic existing Defect pages that include existing fields and the new custom multiObjectpicker, to allow user inputs and write changes into Rally.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to update and create records using WS API: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/ See AppSDK2rc2 documentation: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/ You may create and update records: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/guide/data_models

Comment: Ok thank you. Our requirement is to make combobox multiselect. To achieve this, I guess we have to write an application using WebServices API and users have to switch to new custom screens. :-(

Comment: Another question. How are the application developed using the webservices api deployed and made available as part of Rally?

Comment: See the links to custom html app help document in my answer: https://help.rallydev.com/custom-html as well as the link to AppSDK2 documentation: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/ AppSDK is built on top of WS API so the familiarity with Rally object model is necessary.